# Raycast passes through objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

My raycast passes through objects with mesh collider/box collider with layers.

I can't seem to find a solution. Please help me.

I tried different solutions but the raycast still passes through objects. Even objects behind intractable objects are also being called out.

```
 public float maxRayDistance = 2.0f;

 public LayerMask layerMask;
 public GUISkin mySkin;
 public bool showGui = false;
 public RaycastHit hit;

 void Update()
 {
     Vector3 dir = gameObject.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
     if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dir, out hit, maxRayDistance, layerMask))
     {
         showGui = true;
         if (Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
         {
             Invoke("SendAction", 0.3f);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         showGui = false;
     }
 }

 public void SendAction()
 {
     GameObject target = hit.collider.gameObject;                
     target.BroadcastMessage("Action");
 }
```

[Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWh9p.png)

[Object with Layer other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBgE.png)

Comment: Can you show your configured layer mask in the inspector?

Comment: Yep, I just added a screenshot of it

Comment: Actually you did not, we want to see the gameObject the posted script is attached to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check IsTrigger in Collider (UnityEditor) to have Raycast working on your object.
If this is not working, there is a setting in your projets about Raycast that you might have turned off in Physics Settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! Checking out the physics settings actually worked. I forgot to tick one of the layers there. Cheers!